# Como mostrar opçoes de um select de acordo com a data escolhida?

Tags: html5, select, selected-option

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um site de agendamento de laboratórios e  precisava fazer uma condição em que de acordo com a data que o usuario escolher ele irá consultar no banco de dados todos os laboratorios que estão cadastrado nessa data e colocar no select somente os laboratorios que não estão cadastrado na mesma, para que o usuario possa escolher qual laboratório ele quer.

- Como poderia fazer essa condição?
- Terei que utilizar a condição com javascript ou dá para fazer só com
  o php?

O código se encontra a seguir:

```html
<?php 
  $titlepag="";
  include("includes/headeragenda.php");
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title><?php echo $titlepag ?></title>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP DATAPICKER -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- aqui termina o codigo bootstrap -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css"/>
<!-- 2 FUNÇOES EM JAVASCRIPT PARA O ACTION DO FORMULARIO -->


<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function Verificar()
   {
     document.agendaDATA.action="?acao=verificar";
     document.forms.agendaDATA.submit();
     
   }
function Agendar()
   {
     document.agendaDATA.action="?acao=agendar";
     document.forms.agendaDATA.submit();
     
   }
$(function() {
    $("#tData").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        minDate:"+1", maxDate: "+5M"

    });
});
  </script>


</head>
<body>
<!-- CONTAINER 1 DE ESCOLHA DE DATA PARA AGENDAMENTO -->
    <div id="seldata" class="bradius">
    
        <div><h2 style="text-align: center;">Agendar Data</h2></div><br>
        <div class="message" style=""<?php echo $display;?>"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
        <!--- Formulario de Agendamento -->
       <form name="agendaDATA" method="post">
       <!-- Formulario de verificação de LAbs disponivel -->
        <fieldset id="verificacao" class="bradius"><legend style="text-align: center;"><strong>Verificar se há laboratórios disponível</strong> </legend>
        <!--INPUT DATE PARA SELECIONAR A DATA - SÓ FUNCIONA NO NAVEGADOR GOODLE CHROME-->
        <label for="tData"><strong>Selecione a Data</strong></label><input style="margin-left: 25px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; " class="txt bradius" type="text" id="tData" name="cData"  placeholder=" Dia/Mês/Ano " />
        <br/><br/>
        <!-- RADIOBUTTONS PARA ESCOLHER PERIODO NOTURNO OU DIURNO -->
              <div id="acomodar" style="margin-left: 10px;">
               <strong> Selecione o Periodo</strong>
            <input style="margin-left: 6px;" checked type="radio" id="tNoit" name="cPeriod" value="Noite"/><label for="tNoit">Noite</label>
            <input type="radio" id="tManh"   name="cPeriod" value="Manha"/><label for="tManh">Manhã</label><br>
            
       <!-- BOTÃO COM SCPRIT QUE ENVIA ACTION VERIFICAR PARA O HEADERAGENDA -->     
       <input type="submit" class="sb bradius" value="Verificar" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="Verificar()" />
        </div>
     </fieldset><br>
     <!--TERMINA FORMULARIO DE VERIFICAÇÃO DO LAB -->
     <!--COMEÇA O PREENCHIMENTO DA 2ª PARTE DO FORMULARIO -->
     <!-- INPUT TEXT PARA QUANTIDADE DE ALUNOS QUE VAI TER (ESTIMATIVA) --> 
  <label for="tQuant"><strong> Quantidade de Alunos</strong></label><input style="margin-left: 25px;" id="tQuant" type="text" class="txt bradius" name="cQuant"/> 
   <!-- SELECT COM OS NOSSOS LABORATORIOS E O NUMERO DE MAQUINAS DISPONIVEIS EM CADA LAB -->
   <label for="tLab"><strong> Laboratório</strong></label>
   <select style="margin-left: 25px;" id="tLab" name="cLab" class="txt bradius">
       <option value="">Escolha um Laboratório:</option>
    <option value="Laboratorio 1">Laboratório 1 - 45 Computadores</option>
    <option value="Laboratorio 2">Laboratório 2 - 45 Computadores</option>
    <option value="Laboratorio 3">Laboratório 3 - 30 Computadores</option>
    <option value="Laboratorio 4">Laboratório 4 - 30 Computadores</option>
    <option value="Laboratorio 7">Laboratório 7 - 52 Computadores</option>
    <option value="Laboratorio 8">Laboratório 8 - 52 Computadores</option> 
   </select><br>
  <br/>
  <!-- FIELDSET PARA ESCOLHA DOS EQUIPAMENTOS NECESSARIOS NO LABORATORIO -->
  <fieldset  class="bradius"><legend style="text-align: center;"><b> Selecione os equipamentos </b></legend>
   <input checked type="checkbox" name="cDshow" id="tDatashow" style="margin-left: 6px;" value="Sim" /> Datashow <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cMic" id="tMic" style="margin-left: 6px;" value="Sim" /> Microfone <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cSom" id="tSom" style="margin-left: 6px;" value="Sim"> Caixa de Som
  </fieldset><br/>
  <!-- AREA DE TEXTO PARA O USUARIO ESCREVER PROGRAMA QUE DESENHA UTILIZAR NO LABORATORIO -->
  <label><strong>Softwares (Opcional)</strong><textarea name="cSof" id="tSof" rows="10" style="margin-left: 10px;" cols="38" class="textog bradius" placeholder="Digite o nome dos Programas"></textarea></label><br>
  <input type="submit" class="sb bradius" value="Agendar" style="margin-left: 25px;" onclick="Agendar()" />
  </form>
       
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Esse é meu primeiro site, não sou formado em CC nem nada, apenas fiz tecnico de informática, então desculpem se fiz alguma besteira em alguma parte do codigo, eu ainda estou me adaptando a isso! Criticas e sugestões SEMPRE seram bem vindas por minha parte!

Obrigado!

Comment: Posta o que você tem, mas já adiantando, você terá que enviar através de uma requisição AJAX a data selecionada para o PHP, fazer as buscas necessárias no banco de dados e popular o `select` com o retorno. Se utilizar JSON, a comunicação JS/PHP fica bem tranquila.

Comment: Ninguem consegue me explicar como posso resolver meu problema???